# Re-inserting escapes into a filename with spaces printed to the terminal by a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

My bash script gets filenames with spaces and other odd characters.

How do I print these filenames back out to the terminal with the escapes in the right places so the user can just copy-and-repaste the filename so that it can be reused as a parameter to the same or another script?

I wrote a test script which reads as follows:

```
    #! /bin/bash

    echo ""
    echo "testing the insertion of '\' in filenames having spaces"
    echo "the parameter you gave was: '$1'"
    echo "when printed directly the filename looks like: '$1'"
    echo "when printed with echo \$(printf '%q' $x) it looks like: " $(printf '%q' $1)
```

Running the script went as follows:

```
    bash test.sh this\ filename\ has\ spaces
    testing the insertion of '\' in filenames having spaces

    the parameter you gave was: 'this filename has spaces'
    when printed directly the filename looks like: 'this filename has spaces'
    when printed with echo $(printf '%q' ) it looks like:  thisfilenamehasspaces
```

What I want to see the script produce is:

```
    when printed directly the filename looks like: 'this\ filename\ has\ spaces'
```

Seems simple but the question is hard to form for Google.  All help appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You might need to double quote your parameter when presenting it to printf.

Comment: Just to be clear - I'm trying to insert escape characters into the output so that the output can be cut-and-pasted by the user back into the command line of the bash shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
printf '%q' $1
```

means this:

```
printf '%q' this filename has spaces
```

which, since `printf '%q'` concatenates its arguments, means this:

```
printf '%q' thisfilenamehasspaces
```

What you want is this:

```
printf '%q' "$1"
```

which tells `printf '%q'` that `this filename has spaces` is all one argument, so it will quote the spaces inside.

I'd also recommend putting the command-substitution inside double-quotes:

```
echo "when printed with echo \$(printf '%q' $x) it looks like: $(printf '%q' "$1")"
```

which happens not to be necessary in this case, but will be necessary if the filename ever has a character that causes `printf '%q'` to use `$'...'`-style quoting instead of backslashes.

Comment: Thank you for saving me quite a few hours of searching.